# Use custom tick marks on axes coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting some function in matplotlib. But I want to change the usual x and y coordinates. For example I plot `y=sin(x)` in `[-pi, pi]`. But the x-axis shows `1, 2, 3,...` in this way whereas I want x: `-pi, 0, pi,...` Is it possible?

**My Code**

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rc('text', usetex = True)
mpl.rc('font', family = 'serif')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.style.use(['ggplot','dark_background'])

x = np.arange(-np.pi,np.pi,0.001)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$y$')
plt.plot(x,y, label='$y=\sin x$')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**Output**
[image]

How to change the marks on the axes coordinates? Thank you.

Comment: @roganjosh...I want to change the coordinate axes values from -1,0,1 to -pi,0,pi....Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have custom tick marks on the axis, and set them equally spaced; for this you need to set the tick marks as a sequence, together with the values associated:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rc('text', usetex = True)
mpl.rc('font', family = 'serif')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.style.use(['ggplot','dark_background'])

x = np.arange(-np.pi,np.pi,0.001)
y = np.sin(x)

# the following two sequences contain the values and their assigned tick markers
xx = [-np.pi + idx*np.pi/4 for idx in range(10)]
xx_t = ['$-\\pi$', '$\\frac{-3\\pi}{4}$', '$\\frac{-\\pi}{2}$', '$\\frac{-\\pi}{4}$', '0', 
        '$\\frac{\\pi}{4}$', '$\\frac{\\pi}{2}$', '$\\frac{3\\pi}{4}$', '$\\pi$']
plt.xticks(xx, xx_t)   # <-- the mapping happens here

plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$y$')
plt.plot(x,y, label='$y=\sin x$')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This requires still manually changing the `xx_t ` if we go from \pi i to 2\pi instead of  generating it with a `for` loop. Perhaps it would be helpful to write some sort of loop to generate the labels automatically rather than typing them manually for a larger x range. Anyway, the OP seems to be unclear regarding the end points. He initially said, -\pi to \pi, then -2\pi to 2\pi and then again -\pi to \pi.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can display up to whichever range of pi you want to. Just add the following lines to your code after `plt.plot`

```
xlabs = [r'%d$\pi$'%i if i!=0 else 0 for i in range(-2, 3, 1)]
xpos = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 5)
plt.xticks(xpos, xlabs)
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Thanks..This is close to my answer....but I want x- coordinate...for example..x=-2\pi,-\pi,0,\pi,2\pi...(equally Spaced nodes)...Is it possible....??

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I want x-coordinate". Up to what limit of x do you want to display? -2*pi up to 2*pi?

Comment: Ok, see my edited answer. Now you can put any value up to which you want to display \pi. Don't forget to change the value of x you are using to plot the curve